# How do I show that whether a PDA accepts some string w is decidable? or undecidable?

Tags: automata, undecidability, pushdown-automata

Currently studying for an Automata Theory final and can't find an answer to this question anywhere.

Can you simply let w = w!w and show that it is undecidable that way? Like this here: [How do I show that whether a PDA accepts some string $\{ w!w \mid w \in \{ 0, 1 \}^*\}$ is undecidable?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6626/how-do-i-show-that-whether-a-pda-accepts-some-string-ww-mid-w-in-0-1)

Or do I have to show decidability for arbitrary string w.

Thanks

Comment: There is a difference between a single string "decide whether a given string $w$ is accepted" and  a pattern "decide whether any string of the form $w!w$ is accepted".

Answer (score 1):

Given a PDA and a string $w$, there are several algorithms that decide whether the PDA accepts $w$. In fact, for a fixed PDA, such algorithms run in time $O(|w|^3)$ or less. The most well-known algorithm is the [CYK algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm). Although CYK expects the language in the form of a context-free grammar rather than in the form of a PDA, there is an algorithm that converts a PDA to a context-free grammar generating the same language.

I expect every decent textbook on automata theory to contain a proof that the *acceptance problem* for PDAs (given a PDA and a string, determine whether it accepts the string) is decidable, say along the lines above.

Comment: You mean after a PDA to CFG conversion?

Comment: PDA, CFG, it's all the same. Right, so there is an extra step needed...